# Cannot connect to remote MDB on wildfly - Name not found

Tags: java, jms, wildfly

I have an issue with connecting to wildfly remote queue.

My MDB on wildfly instance is:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "HelloWorldQueueMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
public class HelloWorldQueueMDB implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldQueueMDB.class.toString());

    /**
     * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
     */
    public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
        TextMessage msg = null;
        try {
            if (rcvMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                msg = (TextMessage) rcvMessage;
                LOGGER.info("Received Message from queue: " + msg.getText());
            } else {
                LOGGER.warning("Message of wrong type: " + rcvMessage.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and the standalone client is:

```
public class HelloWorldJMSClient {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJMSClient.class.getName());

    // Set up all the default values
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "quickstartUser";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "quickstartPwd1!";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context namingContext = null;

        try {
            String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
            String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

            // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            log.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\"");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
            log.info("Found connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\" in JNDI");

            String destinationString = System.getProperty("destination", DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            log.info("Attempting to acquire destination \"" + destinationString + "\"");
            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(destinationString);
            log.info("Found destination \"" + destinationString + "\" in JNDI");

            int count = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("message.count", DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT));
            String content = System.getProperty("message.content", DEFAULT_MESSAGE);

            try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(userName, password)) {
                log.info("Sending " + count + " messages with content: " + content);
                // Send the specified number of messages
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    context.createProducer().send(destination, content);
                }

                // Create the JMS consumer
                JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
                // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
                    log.info("Received message with content " + text);
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                try {
                    namingContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error output is:

```
pro 10, 2020 1:49:20 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Found connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" in JNDI
pro 10, 2020 1:49:20 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Attempting to acquire destination "queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue"
pro 10, 2020 1:49:20 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
SEVERE: queue -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.queue
```

I'm using wildfly 21 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the wildfly management console I can see the MDB:

```
URI
java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue

Class Name
org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue

Value
ActiveMQQueue[jms.queue.HelloWorldMDBQueue]
```

**Update:**

Executed:

```
jms-queue add --queue-address=HelloWorldQueueMDB --entries=queue/HelloWorldQueueMDB,java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/HelloWorldQueueMDB
```

on wildfly side I got:

```
15:05:27,427 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (default I/O-53) AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
```

**Update:**

java/security/acl/Group was removed from java14, so using an older version of java works.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to access a Queue remotely and not an MDB. Your queue should be exposed externally using the jboss/exported namespace.
java:jboss/exported/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue would work and make the queue available.
You can take a look at WildFly HelloworlJms quickstart or HelloworldMdb for such an example

Comment: That is actually the code from the quickstart examples. I just had some progress with executing jms-queue add --queue-address=HelloWorldQueueMDB --entries=queue/HelloWorldQueueMDB,java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/HelloWorldQueueMDB.

Comment: iirc the quickstart does create the queues